# Do check_nrpe checks work in OMD installation?

Tags: nagios

I have OMD installation on one of my VM and need to test one of my script that uses nrpe service .

Can someone please confirm for the below :

Do check_nrpe checks work in OMD installation ?

Answer (score 0):

check_nrpe definitely works on any Nagios installation. OMD = Nagios => So the answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 0):

OMD contains nagios, along with the standard nagios plugins. Just locate the nagios configuration directory (most likely /omd/sites/(YOUR SITE)/etc/nagios/conf.d/) and you can configure the way omd behaves as you would with a standalone nagios installation.

the check_nrpe plugin is available as standard, and the "check_nrpe" command should already be present within the commands.cfg file. Just edit your services in that directory, and if the path to the check_nrpe plugin is correct within the commands.cfg file, then it can be used as normal.